# EF Core store class instance inside containing instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Lest's say I have a class Document

```
Class Document
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public ILanguage language {get;set;}
}
```

Where ILanguage is an interface of language that can be French, English...

```
[Some_magic_EF_Attributes("Fr")]
Class FrenchLanguage:ILanguage
{
 //...
}
```

So what I'm trying to archive is with EF Core to store this in DB with this kind of format:

```
Table Documents
 column ID Int
 column Name NVarchar(xxx)
 column Language NvarChar (2)
```

That could contains for instance:

```
{id:1,Name:Fromage,Language:fr}
{id:1,Name:chees,Language:En}
```

Is this possible ?

Thx

Comment: It's unclear how`ILanguage` looks like and how `fr` is related to `French` class

Comment: EF requires entity classes (does not work with interfaces), so the answer is no.